# How to avoid localhost.example.com resolve to localhost address?

Tags: networking, dns, localhost, windows-server

I have a domain, for example, example.com, whose DNS is hosted in http://freedns.afraid.org.

Strangely, when testing web site for vulnerabilities, I've found that when using `localhost.example.com`, 127.0.0.1 is resolved. Why is that and how can I avoid it? In `afraid.org` there is no localhost entry as an A record.

In the server itself, there is no localhost entry in `/etc/hosts` file.

This is a Windows 2016 server.

Answer (score 0):

If your DNS for your Domain *example.com* is hosted at *freedns.afraid.org* it could be, that there is an entry for *localhost.example.com* to 127.0.0.1. Open a CMD with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> *"cmd"* -> Enter and type this commands:

```
nslookup
server freedns.afraid.org
localhost.example.com
```

Comment: Yes... it resolved to 127.0.0.1, however, there is no entry in the zone. Or is this an issue with that server?

Comment: and if you resolve `localhost.google.com` or something like that? Perhaps your DNS resolves every host with localhost to 127.0.0.1. If so, then I think it is an issue with that specific server.

Comment: No, localhost.google.com is not resolved.